# Return several values ​from a matching function using a dictionary with python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dictionary

I am in the process of developing a small script which allows me to retrieve the values ​​of a dictionary if the condition is met.

if the condition is fulfilled I retrieve the key of the dictionary in the cell of my columns in my dataframe.

However, where I get stuck is that I can only retrieve one value from my dictionary while my initial values ​​validate other conditions.

what i have :

| Name | shopping list | cat_and_subcat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | apple , sirop , carotte | Fruit - Apple |
| nick | chocolate, banana, apple minie | Cake - Oreo |
| julie | juice | Fruit - Lemon |

what i should have :

| Name | shopping list | cat_and_subcat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | apple , sirop , carotte | Fruit-Apple , Cake-Carote cake |
| nick | chocolate, banana, apple minie | Cake - Oreo , Fruit - Apple |
| julie | juice | Fruit - Lemon |

How do I get to return all the values ​​of the conditions that are true in the same cell?

```
# Import  library
import pandas as pd
import re

# initialize list of lists
data = [
    ["tom", "apple , sirop , carotte"],
    ["nick", "chocolate, banana, apple minie"],
    ["julie", "juice"],
]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "shopping list"])

# print dataframe.
df


def create_dict():
    # Separator
    sep = " - "
    # cat
    fruit = "Fruit"
    cake = "Cake"
    # sub cat
    apple = "Apple"
    lemon = "Lemon"
    oreo = "Oreo"
    carote_cake = "Carote cake"

    category_uri_dict_reg_match = {
        fruit: {
            apple: ["apple", "apple minie"],
            lemon: ["juice"],
        },
        cake: {
            carote_cake: ["carotte", "betacarotten"],
            oreo: ["chocolate", "crunchy cake"],
        },
    }

    # compile regexp one for all for performance matters
    category_dict_reg_match = {}
    for cat, cat_dict in category_uri_dict_reg_match.items():
        category_dict_reg_match[cat] = {}
        for sub_cat, raw_reg_list in cat_dict.items():
            reg_list = []
            for raw_regex in raw_reg_list:
                reg_list.append(re.compile(raw_regex))
            # print(reg_list)
            category_dict_reg_match[cat][sub_cat] = reg_list
    return category_dict_reg_match


dictio = create_dict()


def get_cat_and_subcat(topic):
    topic = re.sub("", "", topic)
    for cat, cat_dict in dictio.items():
        for sub_cat, reg_list in cat_dict.items():
            if any(compiled_reg.match(topic) for compiled_reg in reg_list):
                return cat + sep + sub_cat
    return "NO_MATCH"


df["cat_and_subcat"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: get_cat_and_subcat(x["shopping list"]), axis=1
)

df
```

Comment: Your code specifically returns as soon as it finds the first match.  You have to accumulate the matches in a list or other structure.  When you finish the loop, then you return the list.  Look for a secondary tutorial on functions, or simply search how to return multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` tries to find a match only at the beginning of the string, while `search` checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default) in Python. In addition, your code returns instantly if it finds a match. You can modify your code as follows:

```
def get_cat_and_subcat(topic):
    sep = " - "
    topic = re.sub("", "", topic)
    results = []
    for cat, cat_dict in dictio.items():
        for sub_cat, reg_list in cat_dict.items():
            if any(compiled_reg.search(topic) for compiled_reg in reg_list):
                results.append(cat + sep + sub_cat)
    if 0 == len(results):
        return "NO_MATCH"
    return ", ".join(results)
```

Result:

```
    Name                   shopping list
0    tom         apple , sirop , carotte
1   nick  chocolate, banana, apple minie
2  julie                           juice
    Name                   shopping list                     cat_and_subcat
0    tom         apple , sirop , carotte  Fruit - Apple, Cake - Carote cake
1   nick  chocolate, banana, apple minie         Fruit - Apple, Cake - Oreo
2  julie                           juice                      Fruit - Lemon
```

Comment: it works great, the mistake I made was forgetting the append function and a bad use of .match(). it will not happen twice thank you very much for your intervention. It helps me enormously to understand.